# Non-local order parameter for Kosterlitz–Thouless transition

Tags: condensed-matter, phase-transition, topological-order, critical-phenomena

It is known, that there's no local order parameter in Kosterlitz-Thouless transition.

**Is the order parameter in Kosterlitz-Thouless transition non-local?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correlation function have different behaviour:
$$
\langle\psi(x)\psi^\dagger(y)\rangle \sim \frac{e^{-r/\xi}}{\sqrt{r}}
\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; T \gg T_c
$$
$$
\langle\psi(x)\psi^\dagger(y)\rangle \sim \frac{1}{r^\eta}
\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; T\ll T_c
$$

This suggests that there may be a phase transitions between them. The fact that the **order parameter for this phase transition is non-local – it involves the position of fields at two distinct points** rather than one is our first hint that this phase transition has a slightly different smell from others.

**Non-local order parametr is correlation function.**